# Finding execption using WinDbg

Tags: c++, windbg, ibm-mq

I build my 32 bit application file in windows 2008 server machine using visual studio 2010. this 32 bit application will use **IBM wepshere MQ Client ( 7.5.0.3).**

while running in the debugging mode i am getting exception so i debugged using WinDbg software

dump info is

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqe.dll - 


FAULTING_IP: 
ntdll32!RtlpCreateSplitBlock+47b
77d23fcb 8b11            mov     edx,dword ptr [ecx]

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000077d23fcb (ntdll32!RtlpCreateSplitBlock+0x000000000000047b)
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
   Parameter[1]: 000000003b9ac9ff
Attempt to read from address 000000003b9ac9ff

CONTEXT:  0000000000000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
eax=0adaff08 ebx=02960000 ecx=3b9ac9ff edx=00100000 esi=0ae2bf90 edi=02960174
eip=77d23fcb esp=079bd490 ebp=079bd4b4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010246
ntdll32!RtlpCreateSplitBlock+0x47b:
77d23fcb 8b11            mov     edx,dword ptr [ecx]  ds:002b:3b9ac9ff=????????

FAULTING_THREAD:  000000000000046c

PROCESS_NAME:  MessageBroker.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000003b9ac9ff

READ_ADDRESS:  000000003b9ac9ff 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
ntdll32!RtlpCreateSplitBlock+47b
77d23fcb 8b11            mov     edx,dword ptr [ecx]

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  messagebroker.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17298 (debuggers(dbg).141024-1500) amd64fre

**BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_ZEROED_STACK**

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_POINTER_READ

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000077d23c5a to 0000000077d23fcb

**STACK_TEXT:**  
079bd4b4 77d23c5a 0ae2bf90 0adaff08 02960150 ntdll32!RtlpCreateSplitBlock+0x47b
079bd5a0 77d23cfe 00000840 00000848 0ae2b74a ntdll32!RtlpAllocateHeap+0xb5d
079bd624 74e04d83 02960000 00000000 00000840 ntdll32!RtlAllocateHeap+0x23a
079bd644 008a8894 00000840 00000002 079bd800 MSVCR80!malloc+0x7a
**WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 mqe+0x68894**


STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr 0x0 ; kb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  ntdll32!RtlpCreateSplitBlock+47b

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: ntdll32

IMAGE_NAME:  ntdll32.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  51fb1072

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_ntdll32.dll!RtlpCreateSplitBlock

**BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_INVALID_POINTER_READ_ZEROED_STACK_ntdll32!RtlpCreateSplitBlock+47b**

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:invalid_pointer_read_c0000005_ntdll32.dll!rtlpcreatesplitblock

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {c09c2d45-666c-6fbd-b6fd-d9b79ba8c4fa}
```

Above dump show that Mqe.dll(IBM WebSphere MQ dll) is passing invalid pointer

Based on the above dump i am unable find the issue.  The stack call very small so i am unable to find where my application calling MQ application ( Mqe.ddl).

Please suggest me how to find the issue and how to debugging Mqe.dll.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MQE.dll is quite possibly an innocent bystander here. It is definitely allocating memory via `malloc`, and then the crash happens inside of the memory manager. This is typically a result of memory corruption that happened at some point in the past. Buffer overflow, underflow, or use-after-free are the typical reasons for heap corruption.

Options to help track the issue down:

1. Use `!heap -v` in WinDbg to perform a heap analysis on the minidump.
2. Analyze the memory around where the memory manager is attempting to work, you may identify some know data (such as strings) that might give you hints as to who corrupted the memory.

   - I would walk backwards in the assembly and figure out where the read address (0x3b9ac9ff) came from.
   - The current registers may also contain pointers inside the heap where things are bad, you also use those as starting points for investigating.
3. Rerun the application with [`PageHeap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561.aspx) to try and catch an overflow immediately when it happens.
4. Code review your allocations and uses of any heap memory.

Comment: Additionally, enable "Application Verifier" and anything with the word "heap" in the "Image File" tab of gflags.exe (which ships with windbg and lives in the same folder as it). Your exe name goes in the text box at the top of that tab.

Comment: Also do a :

kvn 999

maybe you then  see more stack and can see
the culprit straight away.  NB also do the !heap -v